# Shopify getJSON API call to get the countryCode

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, shopify

I'm trying to return the country code from the IP address by making a JSON call to [http://ip-api.com/json][1] [1]: http://ip-api.com/json and then I would like to write the currency code to a cookie, and then update the currency for the entire site.

The code I have at the moment is below (HTML and CSS are from jsfiddle and not part of the code), it works on jsfiddle but I just cannot seem to get it to work in my store on Shopify.

```js
$.getJSON('http://ip-api.com/json', function (location) {

    if (location.countryCode == 'AU') {
       $('#currencies').text("AUD");
        Currency.cookie.write('AUD');
        Currency.convertAll(Currency.currentCurrency, 'AUD');
    }
     else {
       $('#currencies').text("EUR");
        Currency.cookie.write('EUR');
        Currency.convertAll(Currency.currentCurrency, 'EUR');
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    font-size: 75%;
    font-family:"Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}
#body {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 534px;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin-top: 0.75em;
    border: 0 none;
    margin-top:35px;
}
#body td {
    padding:15px 30px 15px 10px;
}
#body tr td:nth-child(1) {
    font-weight:bold;
}
#address {
    width:400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="body">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Currency:</td>
            <td id="currencies"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is my first time coding with JS and making JSON calls, so I'm not too sure if it's a syntax error when using jQuery in Shopify or some other issue?
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `.text` is a valid usage. Try this

```
$.getJSON('http://ip-api.com/json', function (location) {
    if (location.countryCode == 'AU') {
       $('#currencies').html('AUD');
        Currency.cookie.write('AUD');
        Currency.convertAll(Currency.currentCurrency, 'AUD');
    }
     else {
       $('#currencies').html('EUR');
        Currency.cookie.write('EUR');
        Currency.convertAll(Currency.currentCurrency, 'EUR');
    }
});
```

Also IMHO `localStorage` is a better option for cookies. - http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Update from discussion in comments:

```
$.getJSON('https://geoip.nekudo.com/api/', function (location) {
    if (location.country.code == 'AU') {
       $('#currencies').val('AUD');
        Currency.cookie.write('AUD');
        Currency.convertAll(Currency.currentCurrency, 'AUD');
    }
     else {
       $('#currencies').val('EUR');
        Currency.cookie.write('EUR');
        Currency.convertAll(Currency.currentCurrency, 'EUR');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on localstorage, unfortunately I tried your code and it didn't work. I look into the innerHTML function a little more to understand what it does. Thanks

Comment: Can you share the error, if any, that you can see in the browser console?

Comment: Because it is in Shopify no error is shown, it's a case of trial and error I think. I test by editing the code and then refreshing my website.

Comment: try `$('#currencies').html('AUD')` and `$('#currencies').html('EUR')` instead and let me know if it works. I mixed JS and jQuery by mistake.

Comment: I gave that a go, but no luck. Previously it worked with .val when I was using https://freegeoip.net/ but with http://ip-api.com I'm struggling to get it to work.

Comment: Can you provide the link of the page where I can check it out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108814/discussion-between-hymnz-and-shauno-88).